# Turing's Symmetries

Tags: geometry, symmetry, biology

In Alan Turing's classic paper on the [Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rstb.1952.0012), the following bilateral and left-right symmetries are defined as follows:

[image]

Might be an misunderstanding of English from my side, but I can't really visualize this non-parallel upright strokes and what makes it different from the bilateral symmetry. This is what I'm imagining

[image]

Is that what he means? He goes further to define P- and F-symmetries, which is also a bit confusing with the 'coal scuttle' example:

[image]

Any suggestions on where I could learn more about this? Are there more mathematically "better" ways of defining such types of symmetries?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine looking through the $P$ that's closer to you (colored in green below) and right at the $P$ that's on the far side (in red). Namely, you line of sight roughly aligns with the straight line formed by connecting the two $P$s.

[image]

Apologies for the choice of colors. I tried to make the green $P$ thicker to represent that it is closer to your eyes.

The red $P$ is an image of the green (thicker) $P$ via moving along the surface of cylinder (equivalent to rotating in space).

The upright stroke (the "vertical" bar when `P` is written this way) of one is not parallel to the other in the 3-dim Euclidean space.

---

<sup>I don't know how to produce using Mathjax the diagram with two $P$s. The all-powerful `Detexify` returns nothing.</sup>

Comment: I see. What about the F-symmetry?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. It was more than 15 years ago that I read this article, and I apparently remembered wrong. Honestly as of now I'm also very confused about the $F$-symmetry part.